R Synthpop - Unable to write rules to ensure float1 <= float2 <= float3
I have been banging my head against synthpop rules for a few days now and I can't quite understand the documentation for defining rules.  I needed float columns to obey these rules: float1 <= float2 <= float3. I have tried adjusting the visit sequence and predictor matrix to ensure float1 and float3 are synthesized first but nothing seems to work.
Error: Variable(s) used in missing data rules for float2 have to be synthesised BEFORE the variables they apply to.
library(synthpop)



# Create a dummy dataset
size <- 100  # Number of rows

float1 <- runif(size, min = 0, max = 50)
float2 <- runif(size, min = 0, max = 100)
float3 <- runif(size, min = 50, max = 100)

df <- data.frame(float1 = float1, float2 = float2, float3 = float3)

# Define the rules for restricted values
rules <- list(
  float2 = c("float2 < float1", "float2 > float3")
)
rvalues <- list(
  float2 = c("float1", "float3")
)

# Set the visit sequence to ensure float1 and float3 are synthesized before float2
visit.sequence <- c("float1", "float3", "float2")

# Adjust predictor matrix to ensure proper dependency
predictor.matrix <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df))
colnames(predictor.matrix) <- rownames(predictor.matrix) <- colnames(df)
predictor.matrix["float2", "float1"] <- 1
predictor.matrix["float2", "float3"] <- 1

# Use the syn function with the custom rule
syn_data <- syn(df, rules = rules, rvalues = rvalues, visit.sequence = visit.sequence, predictor.matrix = predictor.matrix, seed = 123)


One approach is to split the task into two separate syn runs. The first run returns synthetic float1 and float3 (which float2 depends on) together with an unchanged float2. The second run synthesizes float2 and, afterwards, replaces the synthetic float2 with already synthetic variables from the first run, as specified in the rules.
Example:
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  syn(visit.sequence = c('float1', 'float3'), drop.not.used = FALSE) %>%
  .$syn  %>% ## extract dataframe named 'syn') from first run
  syn(visit.sequence = c('float2')) %>% ## synthesize 'float2'
  .$syn %>% ## see above
  mutate(float2 = case_when(float2 < float1 ~ float1,
                            float2 > float3 ~ float3
  )
  )


some_syn_result$syn extracts the actual synthetic dataframe from the result of a syn run
the actual rules are applied outside the syn function, as part of standard dataframe manipulations
{dplyr} offers provides this pipe operator %>% and convenience functions (mutate, case_when). You could write an equivalent code in base R, but it would become a rather nested construction.

Aside: you can construct the example dataframe in one go like so:
df <- data.frame(float1 = runif(size, min = 0, max = 50),
                 float2 = runif(size, min = 0, max = 100),
                 float3 = runif(size, min = 50, max = 100)
                 )

